# What is the range of int and long as they both are of 4 bytes

Tags: linux, types, i386

How 4 bytes of long have wider range than int?
Source: http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch11.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of that PDF section is to cover situations where `int` and `long` *aren't* the same underlying type. Linux runs on machines as diverse as wristwatches and my big honkin' multi-million dollar mainframe at work.

For example, on `alpha`, `ia64` and `x86_64` (from the table on page 289), `int` is four bytes and `long` is eight bytes:

```
        Size:
arch    char short int long ptr long-long u8 u16 u32 u64
======  ==== ===== === ==== === ========= == === === ===
i386       1     2   4    4   4         8  1   2   4   8
alpha      1     2   4    8   8         8  1   2   4   8
armv4l     1     2   4    4   4         8  1   2   4   8
ia64       1     2   4    8   8         8  1   2   4   8
m68k       1     2   4    4   4         8  1   2   4   8
mips       1     2   4    4   4         8  1   2   4   8
ppc        1     2   4    4   4         8  1   2   4   8
sparc      1     2   4    4   4         8  1   2   4   8
sparc64    1     2   4    4   4         8  1   2   4   8
x86_64     1     2   4    8   8         8  1   2   4   8
```

Hence your question title is a fallacy. A four byte (or eight-byte) `long` would almost certainly have a wider range than a two-byte (or four-byte) `int`.

See the following quote from that PDF:

> The problem is that you can’t use the standard types when you need "a 2-byte filler" or "something representing a 4-byte string", because the normal C data types are not the same size on all architectures.

Answer (score 0):

`int` and `float` have the same number of bits but use different ways of representing numbers:

`float` uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

`int` (usually) uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement